# Installing PHP 5.2 IN CPANEL EASY APACHE 4 at WHM

Tags: php, centos, whm, whmcs, easyapache-4

I am trying to install PHP version 5.2  on CentOS with WHM 86 on EasyApache 4.

I am following this link
https://linuxadmin.io/php-5-2-in-a-cpanel-easyapache4-enviroment/

These line give me error, can someone guide me what does these line of code do as mentioned in the screenshot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v36Wu.png

I am stuck here, any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.php.net/eol.php indicates PHP 5.2 end-of-lifed "6 years, 4 months ago"

Comment: Yes but I still want to install it as our PHP legacy application is running

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.2 has been EOL'ed a long time ago. You shouldn't be using it.
*If* you absolutely need to run it, I'd advise you to use [HardenedPHP](https://www.cloudlinux.com/hardenedphp) by CloudLinux. They've decided to patch old versions of PHP and make them less insecure. It's a part of their CloudLinux distro, so you'll have to pay in order to use it - but it's the only thing I would recommend if you want to use such an old and insecure version of PHP.
CloudLinux is supported by cPanel, and you can migrate from CentOS in a matter of minutes.

If you're fine with using non-patched PHP 5.2, you can also install it from a vendor: [Vendor-provided PHP versions - cPanel](https://docs.cpanel.net/ea4/php/how-to-locate-and-install-a-php-version-or-extension/#vendor-provided-php-versions). I advise against doing it, but it's up to you.